# Selecting an item with the mouse in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, select

This may seem relatively simple, but I'm pretty confused. I have written a mapbasic tool that does things to the table 'Selection' depending on user choices in a popup menu, but currently you need to use the select too to select an item and then run the program. I was wondering how I'd go about selecting an object with a click then it instantly running the main part of the tool?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: I have modified the code in the MapBasic reference guide (as I will only be working with points), however I've gone wrong somewhere as when I click on any point it selects all points in the table! Here is what I have:


http://pastebin.com/4Ee1BdUd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your SQL statement at runtime:

```
comm = "Select * from "+s_table+" where rowid ="+i_row_id+" into Selection" 
Run Command comm
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just:

```
Select * from s_table 
   Where rowid = i_row_id 
   into Selection
```

Comment: I'm thinking that this was probably intended as a Comment on another Answer rather than an Answer in its own right.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well, my answer is another of doing it. The first answer does it using a string built at runtime but it can also be done using a select statement without involving the Run Command statement

Comment: My apologies - I'm not sure where that second comment attributed to me came from but it seems to have been system generated - and I don't think the first (somewhat similar) Answer was there when I reviewed yours and thought it was out of context.  By way of apology I'll upvote your answer.